# Compare Two Array - Delete Matching values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to search `$array_2` for a `json_encode()`'d value from `$array_1`.

If `item_id` in `$array_1` does not match the `item_id` in the `some_field` field in `$array_2` then I need that array index so I can insert that into the database.

I've tried using `in_array()` but that won't work because the arrays have different keys.
Also `array_diff()` will not work because the array indexes have no relation.

$array_1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34
            [item_id] => sfg4et4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 472
            [item_id] => adadgt4
        )
)
```

$array_2;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [some_field] => {"item_id":"mlkjm980"}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [some_field] => {"item_id":"fsff5ssa"}
        )
)
```

Comment: Do the numerical indexes in these arrays have any correlation?  For example do you only want to compare item at index 0 in array 1 to item in index 0 in array 2?  If so, are the arrays guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: No, they don't. Sorry I did not include that. So `array_diff()` will not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the first step would be to put `$array_2` into a usable form.  To do this, I might suggest using `array_walk()` to rewrite this array to be solely a numerically indexed array of item_id values.

```
$array_2 = [...];

array_walk($array_2, function(&$value, $index_not_used) {
    $some_field = json_decode($value['some_field']);
    // overwrite value
    $value = $some_field->item_id;
});
```

`$array_2` is now an array like `['mlkjm980','fsff5ssa', ...]`

Now you can apply `array_filter()` to `$array_1` using this modified `$array_2` array.

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array_1, function ($value) use ($array_2) {
    $item_is_in_array_2 = in_array($value['item_id'], $array_2);
    return !$item_is_in_array_2; // return negation of value as we want to filter out cases where item_id is in $array_2
});
```

Comment: I did something almost just like that )you can see my edit) but the problem is I'll still need the values from `$array_1` so I can insert it into the database.

Comment: @Draven This solution I provided gives you that, as `$filtered_array` is just subset of `$array_1` with matches removed.

Comment: Oh. I'll be back in an hour or so and I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Any way I can get the `id` field after? I need it for later on in the script to UPDATE the database instead of INSERT.

Comment: @Draven The `id` field would still remain in the filtered array.  Again, this approach does not modify the individual array elements in `$array_1` at all, it simply removes the elements you want to filter out.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear enough. I need the `id` field in `$array_1` and it is gone, the only field is `youtube_id`. However, I have fixed my problem, it just look a lot more code then I was hoping for.